# SQL Get all Saturdays between two Dates

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms

I'm trying to find all the saturdays between two dates (inclusive) without using a loop.

For example, April 1, 2021, to May 1, 2021 should return:

```
04-03-2021
04-10-2021
04-17-2021
04-24-2021
05-01-2021
```

Comment: Please tag the database you're using.

Comment: edited but its SSMS

Comment: SSMS is a GUI, presumably you're using Sql Server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `datename`

```
    select *
    from Table
    where Datename(dw,Datecolumn)='Saturday'
    and DateColumn >= start and Datecolumn < End;
```

Alternatively, if you just want to generate a list on the fly, you can do

```
declare @StartDate date = '20210401', @EndDate date = '20210501';

select DateAdd(day, rn-1, @StartDate)
from ( 
    select Row_Number() over (order by object_id) rn
    from sys.columns
 ) d
where rn - 1 <= DateDiff(day, @StartDate, @EndDate)
and DateName(dw, DateAdd(day, rn-1, @StartDate))='Saturday';
```

This first generates a list of numbers in the inner query by utilising one of several possible system tables to select just a `row number`. This is essentially building a *numbers / tally table* on the fly, and it's usually a good idea to have a permanent table like this available (a single column of integers starting at 1 and going up to a squintillion or whatever you need). You can see how this works by just highlighting the inner query and running it (`F5` in SSMS).

An out query selects from this and filters the row numbers to just the right sequential range for the number of days between the two specified dates. Again, you can check this by highlighting the entire query except for the last line, you'll see it generates the list of dates between the specified start and end dates inclusively.

Finally the `and` criteria extracts the name of the day for each date and further filters the list of dates based on the day's name.

Comment: Oh, I didn't see your edit before posting my answer. I'll delete mine.

Comment: @Pierre-AlainVigeant Lolz - I thought it best to offer both as it's not really clear what the intended use-case is. You're right on the use of a numbers table being useful, I have one in every database for many similar uses.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the quick reply! I tested this and it works but... could you please explain what it does? I can understand parts of it but not in its entirety

Comment: @userone Which part - first query or second - is the issue and what specifically?

Comment: the 2nd query and quite frankly, other than the last line (which i assume is filtering by saturday) i can only make guesses

Comment: @userone No problem, I've added a description above, hopefully that helps you follow it!

Comment: @stu yep it took a while but your comment and a few more runs helped me understand it! Basically it's creating X number of rows (number of days from start to end) and adding each day (1, 2, 3, etc.)  from the start date. Lastly it just filters those dates based on specified weekday. Question though, what if there isn't enough columns in sys.columns? IE. I choose two dates thats like a thousand days apart and i have a brand new database?

Comment: Great, glad you got it! If you found it useful, by all means mark it as accepted :-)